# Mongoengine - Query Documents that contain EmbeddedDocuments meeting multiple criteria

Tags: python, mongoengine

**I need to query only the subset of Documents that contain an EmbeddedDocument that meets more than one criteria.**

In the following poorly constructed example, I create two simple Documents...

```py
    from mongoengine import EmbeddedDocument, StringField, IntField, Document, EmbeddedDocumentListField, Q
    class Feature(EmbeddedDocument):
        name = StringField(required=True)
        charges = IntField(required=True)

    class Character(Document):
        name = StringField(required=True)
        features = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Feature)

    c = Feature(name='chair', charges=2)
    u = Feature(name='umbrella', charges=1)
    p1 = Feature(name='potion', charges=1)
    p2 = Feature(name='potion', charges=4)
    m = Character(name='Magnus', features=[c, p1])
    t = Character(name='Taako', features=[u, p2])
    m.save()
    t.save()
```

I then try to query for Documents that contain a Feature named 'potion' with charges less than 3.

```py
    matched_characters = Character.objects(Q(features__name='potion')
                                           & Q(features__charges__lt=3))
    print(matched_characters.to_json())
```

This returns both Documents however, because both contain a Feature named 'potion', and both contain a Feature with charges less than 3, but **what I really want is to only return the Document that has a Feature named 'potion' with less than 3 charges.** How can I accomplish this?

This variant has the same result:

```py
matched_characters = Character.objects(features__name='potion',
                                       features__charges__lt=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `$elemMatch` to ensure that both conditions are being met on the same EmbeddedDocument:

```py
matched_characters = Character.objects.filter(features__match={
    "name": "potion", "charges__lt": 3
})
```

This returns only the Document with a Feature named 'potion' and less than 3 charges.